# Unable to acess iframe's content due to Cross Origin Policy

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, iframe, cross-domain

I have 2 applications both hosted individually. Lets name them App A and App B.

In App A's iframe I am loading the url of App B to perform an action.(It is actually a form submit which contains file upload, but to not reload the page, I'm using an iframe to do that)

While the url is called and the action is performed in App B correctly, I'm unable to read the response in App A.

I'm getting the below JS Exception while reading the response.

> Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "App A URL" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

When the URL is loaded in App A, it is received by a Servlet in App B. The action is performed in App B and response is returned. In App B, I have set the following -

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE");
```

Even by setting Access-Control-Allow-Orgin to *, I'm unable to read the response.

How do I get the response in my iframe?

PS: I don't want to use any third party API.

Comment: try giving the absolute path for the request. ie: localhost as http://localhost